# inserting data into MYSQL database using python

Tags: python

I am trying to insert data into MYSQL database using a python script and when i execute my program i get an error "Not enough arguments for format string" at the following line.

```
_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `md_patentinfo` (patentno, filed) 
       VALUES ('%s',STR_TO_DATE('%s','%M %d,%Y'))" %(patent_number,issue_date))
```

**MORE INFO ON THE ABOVE LINE :**
in the above line i am inserting `patent number` and `Issue date` into my table and i am using the `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the date value in `%B %d,%Y` format to `%M,%d,%Y`.

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the %M, %d and %Y as in:

```
"INSERT INTO md_patentinfo (patentno, filed) VALUES ('%s',STR_TO_DATE('%s','%%M %%d,%%Y'))" % ('123','Apr 14,2012')
```

Comment: when i use this format in .execute(query) i get: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 1):

Your format string has five arguments (each '%something' is an argument).  You probably want to escape the %M, %d%Y part:

```
"INSERT INTO md_patentinfo (patentno, filed) VALUES ('%s',STR_TO_DATE('%s','%%M %%d,%%Y'))" % (patent_number,issue_date)
```